# ¿Por que se congela DOSbox cuando ejecuto este código?

Tags: ensamblador

En teoria estoy sumando dos número con esto pero se congela cuando lo ejecuto.

```
    073F:0100 mov ax,0002;
    073F:0103 mov bx,0004;
    073F:0106 add ax,bx;
    073F:0108 int 21;
    073F:010A
    -g
```

Una vez ejecuto con `-g` se congela el DOSbox.
Soy literalmente nuevo en ensamblador asi que no se que estoy haciendo mal